# Dynamic SQL with varchar in replace of table variable

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, table-variable

I'm pretty new to Dynamic SQL, and SQL Server in general, but I would like to iterate over a table list within `information_schema.tables`. Each iteration has a `varchar` variable listing the Month-Year to be searched within the table name (`where table_name like concat('USA_RETHHDs_%', @Month)`).

Each table with the matched date would then be placed into a `varchar` variable. The problem is, I want to obtain the `table` variable from the `information_schema.tables` list instead, but am unsure of how this can be done. As a result, I'm trying to go the dynamic route, embedding the `varchar` variable into a dynamic SQL query. However, it's expecting a `table` variable rather than a `varchar`.

```
declare @Month varchar(6)
declare @Table varchar(32)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @MonthCount int

while @MonthCount > 0
    begin
        select @Month = DateSuffix from @DateTable where Row = @MonthCount
        select @Table = table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like concat('USA_RETHHDs_%', @Month)
        select @Table = concat('dbo.', @Table)
        set @sql = 'select * from @Table'
        execute SP_EXECUTESQL @sql  

        select @MonthCount = @MonthCount - 1
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
set @sql = 'select * from ' + @Table
execute SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

I should also mention that you can include the parameter in your `sp_executesql` call

```
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @MonthCount INT
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);


WHILE @MonthCount > 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @Month = DateSuffix
        FROM    @DateTable
        WHERE   Row = @MonthCount

        SELECT  @Table = table_name
        FROM    information_schema.tables
        WHERE   table_name LIKE CONCAT('USA_RETHHDs_%',@Month)

        SELECT  @Table = CONCAT('dbo.',@Table)

        SET     @sql = N'select * from @param '
        SET     @ParmDefinition = N'@param varchar(500)'

        EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @sql, @ParmDefinition, @param = @Table

        SELECT  @MonthCount = @MonthCount - 1
    END
```

Comment: Excellent! So much easier than I thought. Thanks Jamie!